# Gmail weird close button on the right bottom corner

Tags: gmail

I am using Mac, Safari 7.0.2 & facing following issue.

I find a close button on right-bottom corner of Gmail. I tried to click on it, cursor changes to Hand. I tried refreshing Gmail several times. I also logged in with 3 different account. Also, I cleared everything & loaded again. I find it there every time. Is that a bug from Gmail?

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, I also see it on Windows 8 in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read up on this post on Google+: **[Gmail X Bug](https://plus.google.com/111166827982420581810/posts/GnNSrSecMhA)**

The following comment was made as to a work-a-round:

> There is a way to fix this issue. Bookmark this URL: https://mail.google.com/mail/?labs=0 and use it to open Gmail. This URL is used to load Gmail without enabling labs. Surprisingly, if you manually disable all the Gmail labs experiments, the close button is still there.

Of course Google is working on a fix:

> Google is working on a fix. Apparently, this is a leftover from the "about the new look" message that used to be displayed when Gmail launched a new interface back in 2011.

Answer (score 1):

I removed it by doing a Ctrl+F5 or Cmd+Shift+R on Mac